# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file c#

Tags: c#, database, excel, csv, jet

Hi I am having some issues reading a CSV file with the Jet Database engine. I get this message:

```
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\Users\mikec\Desktop\'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
```

I have permission to access this folder and file. I have also tried putting in my Visual Studio project and still get the same error. This is my code

```
string path = @"C:\Users\mikec\Desktop\Book1.csv";

string full = Path.GetFullPath(path);
string file = Path.GetFileName(full);
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(full);

//create the "database" connection string 
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
+ "Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";"
+ "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";

//create the database query
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + file;

//create a DataTable to hold the query results
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString);

//create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);

try
{
    //fill the DataTable
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

}
catch (InvalidOperationException e)
{

}
```

I'm confused to why this is happening I've looked around the Internet and cannot find a solution.

It would be great if anyone out there could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Try moving the file to some neutral (not user specific) location, such as `c:\shared\Book1.csv`. Probably Jet needs write permission in the containing directory.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Do you have 64 bit Windows? There can be [issues](http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/).

Comment: @nrodic, Yeah, sorry about that. I saw that I was wrong and removed the comment... I still think something's going on with the filename, though, due to what the error is saying... Maybe  `"SELECT * FROM [" + file + "]";`?